# Does different collation between the database and columns cause performance issues?

Tags: sql-server, collation

I'm trying to figure out if having a different collation between table columns and the database can cause performance issues.

I ran the first-aid index stuff over at https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/

One of the things that popped up that I've never seen before is:

> Abnormal Psychology: Column collation does not match database collation

So I have a few cases where I have a table with > 1 billion rows that have columns specified as `Latin1_General_CI_AS` where the database is actually configured as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

I'm wondering if this is worth fixing? Does it cause performance issues? I believe it's defaulted to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` because the database was created back on SQL Server 2000 but its currently running on SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I'm not sure about performance issues but it can be an issue when comparing columns (e.g. joins or unions).

Comment: I thought it would only cause problems if 1 was CS and the other was CI. In this case they are both CI.

Comment: Nope, regardless of whether two collations are both case-sensitive (or case-insensitive), it can be a problem. As a general rule, it makes sense. In reality, there's probably not much difference (if any?) between those two collations, but you will still see generic errors about conflicting collations. See, for example: http://rextester.com/NDNI13192

Comment: Thanks for the info!